# Changing static var embedded in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, static

I have a series of videos for the user to choose from. At any point, I want to be able to access the video property by calling `Video.setupFull.watched` and find out if it's `nil` or not. I created a struct and then static variables to create each video.

Here is my setup code:

```
struct Video {
    let name: String
    let image: String
    let firebaseID: String
    let number: Int
    let url: String
    let desc: String
    var playbackTime: TimeInterval?
    var watched: Bool?
    var watchedDate: TimeInterval?

    static let setupFull = Video(name: "Setup Full",
                                 image: "Setup Full",
                                 firebaseID: "setupTutorialFull",
                                 number: 300928943,
                                 url: "https://player.vimeo.com/external/282034045",
                                 desc: "Moneypants Setup Tutorial Full")

    static let step1Income = Video(name: "Step 1 - Income",
                                   image: "Step 1 Income",
                                   firebaseID: "step1Income",
                                   number: 282034041,
                                   url: "https://player.vimeo.com/external/282034041",
                                   desc: "Moneypants Setup Tutorial (Step 1) - Income")

    static let step2FamilyMembers = Video(name: "Step 2 - Family Members",
                                          image: "Step 2 Family Members",
                                          firebaseID: "step2FamilyMembers",
                                          number: 282600740,
                                          url: "https://player.vimeo.com/external/282600740",
                                          desc: "Moneypants Setup Tutorial (Step 2) - Family Members")

    static var array = [setupFull, step1Income, step2FamilyMembers]
}
```

To save space, I only store the optional parameters of the video objects (`playbackTime`, the `watched`, and the `watchedDate`) on Firebase, which looks like this:

```
{
  "setupTutorialFull" : {
    "playbackTime" : 194,
    "watched" : true,
    "watchedDate" : 1550004207
},
  "step1Income" : {
    "playbackTime" : 10,
    "watched" : true,
    "watchedDate" : 1544566787
},
  "step2FamilyMembers" : {
    "playbackTime" : 22,
    "watched" : true,
    "watchedDate" : 1544589461
  }
}
```

(Note that all the videos in the list have been watched.)

I want to do a batch update when I initially load the data, so I made the array of videos and tried to update them like this:

```
static func observeDB(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    FB.ref
        .child(FB.videos)
        .observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            
            for item in snapshot.children {
                
                guard let snap = item as? DataSnapshot else { return }
                guard let value = snap.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                
                let videoID = snap.key
                
                let playbackTime = value[FB.playbackTime] as? TimeInterval
                let watched = value[FB.watched] as? Bool
                let watchedDate = value[FB.watchedDate] as? TimeInterval
                
                // Find the appropriate video and update its variables.
                if let index = array.firstIndex(where: { $0.firebaseID == videoID }) {
                    array[index].playbackTime = playbackTime
                    array[index].watched = watched
                    array[index].watchedDate = watchedDate
                }
            }
            
            completion()
    }
}
```

But, to my dismay, the static variables don't update when the array does.

```
print(Video.setupFull.watched) // prints `nil`
print(Video.array[0].watched) // prints `true`
```

Now if I manually modify the static var directly, it updates. This is expected, of course.

```
Video.setupFull.watched = true
print(Video.setupFull.watched) // prints `true`
```

The problems is I have potentially hundreds of videos to update, though, and don't want to have to manually update each one. That's why I created the `static array`. That way I could iterate over the array and update the videos quickly. I want to be able to call `Video.setupFull.watched` on a separate view controller and it to show `watched`.

My question: Why don't the static variables update when they are embedded in an array? Why can't I use `Video.array[0].watched = true` and it update the underlying `Video.setupFull.watched` object?

I thought that was how structs worked. They don't create copies, but are directly modifiable. What am I missing?

Comment: You are wrong, structs are value types and always create a copy. Classes are reference types, and are modifiable.

Comment: @TusharSharma, so are you suggesting I redo my code using a class?

Comment: I guess I don't understand. I used `static var` elsewhere in my app, and I'm able to update it from other classes and view controllers. Is it because I've embedded them inside an array, that's creating a copy?

Comment: In general global (static) variables is problematic to work with and here you have managed to create duplicates. My suggestion for a quick fix is to skip the individual static objects and only have a static array and instantiate the Video objects when you create the array.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, thanks for the idea. How would I `instantiate` the Video object when I create the array? Would they be accessible as `Video.setupFull.watched`, or would I have to access them only through the array, a la `Video.array[0].watched`?

Comment: Only through the array, otherwise you will have multiple copies. `static array = [Video(name: …), Video(name:…), …]`. Of course you could use a dictionary instead of an array if you think that would the video objects easier to access

Comment: @TusharSharma, I changed my struct to a class, and it works as intended. Thanks for your suggestion. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @PhontaineJudd it’s ok, good to see suggestion helped.